# investigation of some topological properties

Tags: general-topology

There seems to be many lemmas and propositions in these notes where they skip many proofs(which makes my learning rather hard) because maybe the author thinks it is straightforward, but I don't seem to see why it is the case for instance this lemma on interior points:

**Lemma 4.62:** $x \in \text{int} (A),$ iff there is an open set $B$, such that $x\in B$ and $x\in B \subset A. $

This lemma does not seem so straightforward to me, can anyone give me a proof to this? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: First, you must tell us which definition of interior of a set you're using.

Comment: See [Iinterior point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_of_a_set): "If S is a subset of a Euclidean space, then x is an interior point of S if there exists an open ball centered at x which is completely contained in S. The *interior* of a set S is the set of all interior points of S."

Comment: Its very vague, but oh in my notes it says the interior of $A$ is defined as the subset of $A,$ which is the biggest open subset contained in $A.$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis that is actually a strange definition because at the level of defining it is not clear yet that such "biggest open subset of $A$" exists. It is better to define it as in my answer, and to **conclude** on base of that definition that it is indeed the biggest open subset contained in $A$.

Comment: Yes, actually it was a chapter on closure, and this was just stated as a lemma, skipped the proof so I was kind of confused. Thats about the only mentioning of interior points there is in these notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf{int}(A)$ can be defined as union of all open subsets of $A$.

As a union of open sets it is **open itself**, and can be characterized as the "largest" open subset of $A$.

It means actually that: $$B\subseteq A\text{ and }\ B\text{ open }\implies B\subseteq\mathsf{int}(A)\tag1$$

If $x\in\mathsf{int}(A)$ then there is indeed an open set $B$ with $x\in B\subseteq A$ because we can simply take $B=\mathsf{int}(A)$.

If conversely $x\in B\subseteq A$ where $B$ is open then $B\subseteq\mathsf{int}(A)$ as a consequence of $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the fast help, one question, what does the cone sign mean?

Comment: It means "and". I edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to understand the proof.